# Ideas for how to run oscillating stepper motor with bnc input from Labchart8?

Tags: arduino, stepper, motordriver

I would like to build a stepper motor that moves a stick up and down either in a sinusoidal oscillation or following a ramp model (slow lift, sudden drop).

I have a computer program (Labchart8) that easily can set the output voltage in whatever oscillating pattern I like using a graphical representation. This voltage output is then sent to a device via BNC connection from a Powerlab (ADinstruments) DAQ board.

Though i've programmed Arduinos to drive stepper motors before, I am not sure how to go about interfacing a BNC computer output to any commercially available steppermotor driver. I  would love any suggestions for how I might go about constructing such a stepper motor with a BNC digital input. The system I described is nice because I can easily monitor the output stimulus going to the motor, which is essential for the experiments I run but doesn't seem possible via Arduino.

I am not currently aware of any stepper motor systems that can be controlled by BNC input from an external device.